# Sublime Text 3: Hide tab bar in only one view

Tags: sublimetext3

If I have multiple views open in a window in Sublime Text 3, is there a way for me to hide the tab bar in only one of the views, rather than `View > Hide Tabs`, which hides the tab bar in all views?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Except for Justin's [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66703400), there is not a way to do this in a single window. The `toggle_tabs` command is associated with the window, not an individual view, so it operates on all views within a particular window.

Hypothetically, you could write a Python plugin to execute `toggle_tabs` every time you switched to a particular view, but it would have to be file- or file type-specific.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know, I can live without the feature, I just wanted to know if it was a thing.

Answer (score 0):

If its just one view just drag it to make it a new window that way you will have two windows, one with the tabs you wish to see and other with ones you dont want to see